# Why would you write an extension method for a class instead of changing the implementation directly?

Tags: c#

Why would you write an extension method for a class instead of changing the implementation directly?

For instance, if I had the class

```
public class A 
{
    public void someMethod1() {...}
}
```

and I wanted to add some more functionality, then why would I write an extension method, like:

```
public static class AExtensions 
{
    public static void someMethod2(this A a) {...}
}
```

Instead of just changing the implementation directly to

```
public class A 
{
    public void someMethod1() {...}
    public static void someMethod2() {...}
}
```

The extension approach seems a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: You would change the implementation if you needed all object to change their implementation. If you only need *some* objects to change their implementation then you extend the class

Comment: You can also extend classes that you might not have the ability to alter (i.e., external libraries).

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Extension methods do not change implementation - they only add new methods.

Comment: For what it's worth, the title doesn't say what you are asking (in particular, I was expecting a different description).  Inheritance is the standard way of *Extending* a class (i.e., it extends an existing class by adding more state and/or adding additional behavior).  What you are asking about is adding Extension methods to classes (either directly, or through a base class or an interface the class implements)

Comment: The first sentence in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) sums it up pretty well: *"Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type."*

Comment: I don't understand what the question is asking. You *wouldn't* do any of those things normally, so asking why you would do them is a strange thing to ask.  Why are you seeking justifications for doing stuff you already know is wrong? Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 9):

The question is very strange; it appears to be "why would I do things the hard way when I know how to do them the easy way?"  You wouldn't, so asking *why you would* is a strange thing to ask.  You do *not* normally put implementations into an extension method *when you control the type being extended*. Extension methods were not invented for that scenario; they were invented for the *opposite* scenario, where the person doing the extension does *not* control the type.

But let's take the original poster at their word, and see if there are cases where it is reasonable to put functionality into an extension method **even when we control all the definitions**. It's not clear to me why the original poster is looking for an excuse to use this pattern, but let's not worry about that.

Here's one. Follow the logic:

- Let's suppose we have a generic type which we want to use in a covariant or contravariant manner.
- C# only supports generic variance on interfaces and delegates, so the variant parts have to go into an interface.
- Interfaces in C# cannot (yet) support implementations. (This is one of the few Java features I miss from C#, and has been proposed for future revisions of the language. As I write this, the feature is in test versions of C# 8.)
- A feature's signature would prevent the desired variance annotation.
- The desired feature can be implemented as an extension method.

**In that case it is reasonable to implement the feature as an extension method** even if we control the class and the interface.

That was probably pretty abstract. Let's look at an example.  We wish to implement a variant immutable stack. Here's our first attempt:

```
public abstract class Stack<T>
{
    private Stack() {}
    public static readonly Stack<T> Empty = new EmptyStack();
    private sealed class EmptyStack : Stack<T>
    {
      public override bool IsEmpty => true;
      public override T Peek() => throw new Exception("Empty stack");
      public override Stack<T> Pop() => throw new Exception("Empty stack");
    }
    private sealed class Regular : Stack<T>
    {
      private readonly T head;
      private readonly Stack<T> tail;
      public Stack(T head, Stack<T> tail)
      {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
      }
      public override bool IsEmpty => false;
      public override T Peek() => head;
      public override Stack<T> Pop() => tail;
    }
    public abstract bool IsEmpty { get; }
    public abstract T Peek();
    public abstract Stack<T> Pop();
    public Stack<T> Push(T head) => new Regular(head, this);
}
```

OK, first problem: we can't use variance on a class type. It needs to be an interface.  What interface?

```
public interface IStack<out T>
{
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
    IStack<T> Pop();
    T Peek();
```

So far we have no problem with covariance. If we have an `IStack<Mammal>` we can use it as an `IStack<Animal>`, because when we peek a stack of lions, tigers and bears, we get an animal every time.

But what about `Push`?  We cannot write

```
    IStack<T> Push(T t);
```

Because now T is being used in an invalid position.

But let's think about this for a moment. Suppose we have an `IStack<Turtle>`.  **Can we push a Giraffe onto it**?  That sounds wrong; you can't put a giraffe into a list of turtles, so why should you be able to push a giraffe onto a stack of turtles?

But it does work: **a stack of turtles is a stack of animals, and we can push a giraffe onto that**.  So what we need is:

```
public interface IStack<out T>
{
    ...
    IStack<U> Push<U>(U u) where T : U;
}
```

**Which is illegal in C#; there are no such "backwards" constraints.**  (Again, one of the few areas where Java does better.)

OK, we can't have our desired `Push` in the interface. How then are we going to push onto the stack?  We can do this by making only minor changes to the type:

```
public abstract class Stack<T> : IStack<T>
{
    private Stack() {}
    public static readonly Stack<T> Empty = new EmptyStack();
    private sealed class EmptyStack : Stack<T>
    {
      public override bool IsEmpty => true;
      public override T Peek() => throw new Exception("Empty stack");
      public override IStack<T> Pop() => throw new Exception("Empty stack");
    }
    private sealed class Regular : Stack<T>
    {
      private readonly T head;
      private readonly IStack<T> tail;
      public Stack(T head, IStack<T> tail)
      {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
      }
      public override bool IsEmpty => false;
      public override T Peek() => head;
      public override IStack<T> Pop() => tail;
    }
    public abstract bool IsEmpty { get; }
    public abstract T Peek();
    public abstract IStack<T> Pop();
    public static IStack<T> Push(T head, IStack<T> tail) => 
      new Regular(head, tail);
}
```

Super.  What does the call site look like?

```
IStack<Turtle> s1 = Stack<Turtle>.Empty;
IStack<Turtle> s2 = Stack<Turtle>.Push(someTurtle, s1);
IStack<Animal> s3 = Stack<Turtle>.Push(anotherTurtle, s2);
IStack<Animal> s4 = Stack<Animal>.Push(someGiraffe, s3);
```

**It totally works**.  We used a stack of turtles as a stack of animals and pushed a giraffe onto it. But oh my goodness look at how horrid that call site is!

What we need is a way to get the type argument out of the call site, but we can do that with... an extension method!

```
public static IStack<T> Push<T>(this IStack<T> s, T t) => 
  Stack<T>.Push(t, s);
```

And now what do our call sites look like?

```
IStack<Turtle> s1 = Stack<Turtle>.Empty;
IStack<Turtle> s2 = s1.Push(someTurtle);
IStack<Animal> s3 = s2.Push(anotherTurtle);
IStack<Animal> s4 = s3.Push(someGiraffe);
```

Much nicer.  Even better:

```
var s3 = Stack<Turtle>.Empty.Push(someTurtle).Push(anotherTurtle);
var s4 = s3.Push((Animal)someGiraffe);
```

(The requirement of the cast is a little unfortunate; C# type inference will not deduce "I have a turtle and a giraffe, the developer probably meant animal".  Rather, it will deduce "I have a turtle and a giraffe and I do not know which to choose".  The cast helps the compiler resolve the ambiguity.)

So, to answer your question: why would you implement an extension method when you could modify the class?  **You would do that if modifying the class led you to a scenario where the call site had to be ugly, but adding a clever extension method makes for a nice, fluent, pleasant user experience**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use extension methods on classes you don't have access to, for example you could add one to `String` and you can't modify `String` since it's part of .NET. It also means you don't have to have them all the time - like LINQ for example, is a collection of extension methods only available if you add a `using` statement so they don't clog things up unnecessarily. It also keeps code tidier, writing an extension method called `Reverse` and doing `"Hello".Reverse();` is much nicer than `MyExtensionClass.Reverse("Hello");` especially if it appears 50 times on a page like ASP.NET pages often have to deal with when rendering complex models.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is this relevant to classes for which you don't have access to modify yourself, but [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) also work on interfaces, which is where things can get really interesting (and where a lot of LINQ niceness comes from).

So if you have an interface called `IEnumerable<T>`, you can define the following extensions class:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T item in enumerable)
        {
            action(item);
        }

        return enumerable;
    }
}
```

and now that extension method is available *wherever you have anything implementing IEnumerable*.

Which allows you do do this: `list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.SomeProperty))`

But notice how my extension method returns the `IEnumerable<T>`? That is where [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) comes in:

```
list.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == someValue)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated)
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.SomeProperty));
```

Comment: Ha! Many thanks to whoever spotted that despite my claim to the contrary, my extension method had forgotten to return the enumerable. :)